Fundamental group of a Moebius strip through the fundamental polygon method



Note: $\pi$ is the fundamental group functor, I dropped the base point as, all spaces consider path connected and hence all possible pointed spaces have the same fundamental group.
I am trying to apply the Van Kampen theorem on the  quotient rectangle of the moebius strip to be calculate it's fundamental group through a method general to calculating fundamental group of surfaces. For that I take a point in the rectangle and consider two open set, one of an open ball of Radius 'R', one of the complement of a closed ball of radius 'r' smaller than it in the quotient rectangle. I have attached a picture above.
Now to Van Kampen tells me the fundamental group of the moebius strip is $\pi(U) *_{\sim} \pi(V) $ where $\sim$ is the quotient by the normal subgroup generated by the elements of multiplication of inclusion of homotopy class of $U \cap V$ into $U$ and the inverse homotopy class of the included one from $U \cap V$ into $V$.
Of course $\pi(U)$ is trivial (it's that of a disc), but what about $\pi(V)$? Normally we take the deformation retract of $V$ to proceed but here it is unclear to me what the deformation retract of V for moebius strip  with a hole in it should be.
I tried recreate what one would get out of deformation retract the part of $V$ onto the boundary by making the hole bigger and bigger in real life:


The red line denotes the gluing line

In the 3d figure, if one moves their finger along one of the loops, they'd end up on the lower one. This makes me feel the fundamental group must be $\mathbb{Z}$ and the normal subgroup generated by the inclusion be the trivial one.
However, I am unable to make it precise. Could some hints be given on how to argue this more precisely (but still intuitive of course, because I am taking a begineer intuitive approach to AT )

Remark: I am aware of the Deformation retract method of calculating this but my goal is not the fundamental group in itself but an understanding of a correct application of this method.
And also, I am aware I have to think about the fundamental group of the intersection and inclusion of the paths into it. However, that is quite easy, because in this method the intersection gives an annulus which is homotopically equivalent to a circle. The only real problem I have is $V$.

There is too much undefined notation (what is $\pi$? Is it the same as $\pi_1$?), and there are too many grammatical errors, to understand your assertions. It looks like you are saying Van Kampen tells me the fundamental group of the moebius strip is $\pi(U) \cap \pi(V)$ but the Van Kampen theorem does not tell us anything like that. For example, you have failed to mention the free product of the fundamental groups $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$, which is central to the conclusion of the Van Kampen theorem.

I believe I corrected for all the mistakes. I had the right thing in my head but wrote the wrong things when I wrote the question @LeeMosher

What happened to $\pi(U\cap V)$ and its inclusion into $\pi(U)$ and $\pi(V)$? You'd better review the statement of Van Kampen.

I had it since beginning but the latex was wrong. I fixed it now @TedShifrin

Do you need to use Seifert Van-Kampen?
Otherwise, I suggest another possible method.
Let us consider $\mathbb R^2$ and the action of the group generated by the map $f(x,y)=(x,-y)+(1,1)$. this group acts in a properly discontinuous way, so that the quotient map $\pi\colon \mathbb R^2\to M$ is a covering map.
Clearly, as you can expect $M$ is the Möbius Strip, and the above defined covering is the universal covering of $M$. From the theory of covering spaces we have
$$ \pi_1(M)/ \pi_*(\mathbb R^2)=\pi_1(M) \cong \mathbb Z $$
Here $\mathbb Z$ represents the group generated by $f$.

N.b. that if non-van Kampen solutions are allowed it's also not hard to write down a deformation retraction of $M$ onto $S^1$ embedded as the "equator." The covering space solution is very nice, however :)

Your solution is also very nice, you should write it. It could be nice to give a list of methods to compute it

Federico's answer is very nice, but one can also give a direct argument (still not using van Kampen's theorem, however):
Let $S = [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$ and consider $M$ as the quotient $M = S / (1, y) \sim (-1, -y)$, mirroring your drawing. We then have a deformation retraction $h_t\colon S \to S$, $h_t(x, y) = (x, (1 - t) y)$ of $S$ onto the subspace $[-1, 1] \times \{0\} \subset S$. But clearly $h_t$ respects the quotient relation defining $M$, so it descends to a deformation retraction $\overline{h}_t\colon M \to M$ of $M$ onto the image of $[-1, 1] \times \{0\}$ in the quotient, but this is just $[-1, 1] \times \{0\} / (1, 0) \sim (-1, 0) \cong S^1$.
In other words, $M$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$, embedded as the "equator" of the strip, so $\pi_1 M \cong \pi_1 S^1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
